# Помогите составить запрос к модели Django

Tags: python, html, sql, django, django-orm

У меня есть одна проблема. Пишу сайт с видео курсами и на html странице слева есть панель навигации с ссылками на уроки в упорядоченном виде. Ссылка на следующий урок должна отображаться в только в том случае, если домашнее задание к прошлому уроку выполнено верно (поле модели **is_correct** с булевыми значениями). Проблема в том, как грамотно составить запрос, который будет брать предыдущий урок, проверять
его поле **is_correct** и только в этом случае выводить ссылку на следующий (Пример: есть курс с уроками "Урок1, Урок2, Урок3". на html странице на навиг. панели отображется только ссылка на "Урок1", после просмотра видеоролика пользователь прикрепляет в форму д/з и преподаватель из админки в случае правильности д/з ставит галочку в поле "is_correct" и только в этом случае пользователю отобразится ссылка на "Урок 2" в навигационной панели

**Прикрепляю сам код**

*views.py*

```
def lessons_detail(request, pk):
    lesson_item = get_object_or_404(Lessons, pk=pk)
    lessons_nav = Lessons.objects.all()
    prev_lesson = Lessons.objects.filter(pk__lt=pk).order_by('-pk').first()
    lesson_previous = Answers.objects.filter(
        Q(user_answer=request.user) & Q(from_lesson=prev_lesson)
    ).first()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        images = request.FILES.getlist('photos')
        answer = Answers.objects.create(user_answer=request.user, from_lesson=lesson_item,
                                        is_correct=False)
        for image in images:
            Photos.objects.create(
                image=image,
                answer=answer
            )
    return render(request, 'brows/lesson_detail.html', {'lessons': lesson_item,
                                                        'lessons_nav': lessons_nav,
                                                        'lesson_previous': lesson_previous
                                                        })
```

*lessons_detail.html*

```
<aside class="panel">
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-danger">Выйти</a>
    <a href="#"><p>LOGO</p></a>

    {% for i in lessons_nav %}
        {% if i.get_pre %}
            <div class="lesson_link">
                <a href="{{ i.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ i.lesson }}</a>
            </div>
        {% elif i == first %}
            <div class="lesson_link">
                <a href="{{ i.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ i.lesson }}</a>
                <p>{{ lesson_previous.is_correct }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
</aside>
```

*models.py*

```
class Lessons(models.Model):
    lesson = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Урок')
    Video = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Видео')
    abstract = models.TextField(verbose_name='Конспект')
    home_work = models.TextField(verbose_name='Домашнее задание')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.lesson}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Урок'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Уроки'
        ordering = ['pk']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lessons_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Answers(models.Model):
    user_answer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1, verbose_name='Пользователь')
    from_lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lessons, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Урок')
    comments = models.TextField(verbose_name='Комментарий преподавателя', blank=True)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=0, verbose_name='Допуск к следующему уроку')
    next = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='prev')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user_answer}'

    def get_absolute_url(self, from_lesson):
        return reverse('lessons_detail', kwargs={'pk': from_lesson.pk})

    def lesson_prev(self, lesson_next):
        prev_lesson = Lessons.objects.filter(pk__lt=lesson_next).order_by('-pk').first()
        lesson_previous = Answers.objects.filter(
            Q(user_answer=self.user_answer) & Q(from_lesson=prev_lesson)).first()
        return lesson_previous.is_correct

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Ответ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ответы'
        ordering = ['pk']


class Photos(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', verbose_name='Ответ')
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answers, related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.answer}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lessons_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Фото'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Фото'
        ordering = ['pk']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал не искать по `pk__lt`, так как Вы не можете 100% гарантировать, что следущий урок будет с бОльшим `id`.

Например, если нужно будет вставить урок между двумя другими.

Так же проще добавить поле `next = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=..., related_name='prev')`, что позволит Вам обращаться к следущему и прошлому уроку по `obj.next` и `obj.prev`. Даже наверное лучше подойдет `OneToOne` связь.

Что касается "следущий урок в навигационной панели", можете сделать выборку выполненных и/или не выполнных уроков (их `id`) и при выводе смотреть, является ли он выполненным

```
# .py

lessons = Lessons.objects.all()
show_link = lessons.filter(is_correct=True).values_list('id')
# Для моего случая
show_link = lessons.objects.filter(Q(prev__isnull=True) | Q(prev__is_correct=True))


# .html
{% for obj in lessons %}
    {% if obj.in in show_link %)
        {# выполнен #}
    {% else %}
        {# не выполнен #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```